# Sending octet stream

Tags: go

I have two go programs - one running as a server daemon, the other being executed manually. I want to be able to send a request to the server from the other program, sending some binary data there via post request. How can I do this?

I know I can send a string like this:

```
data := url.Values{}
data.Set("req", buf)
u, _ := url.ParseRequestURI(domain)
u.Path = path
urlStr := fmt.Sprintf("%v", u)
client := &http.Client{}
r, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", urlStr, bytes.NewBufferString(data.Encode()))
r.Header.Add("Authorization", "auth_token=\"XXXXXXX\"")
r.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
r.Header.Add("Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(len(data.Encode())))
resp, _ := client.Do(r)
return resp.Status
```

But I want to send an `octet-stream` which I can then read from `ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)`.

Comment: What doesn't work if you just send the data as an `octet-stream` instead of `x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following show how to send data inside the request body to a server, and read it on the server side. The client part is as follow:

```
c := http.Client{}
data := []byte("This is a content that will be sent in the body")
r, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://localhost:8080", bytes.NewBuffer(data))
// You should never ignore the error returned by a call.
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
c.Do(r)
```

And in your http.Handler function:

```
d, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
}

fmt.Println("Request content : ", string(d))
```

This is the easiest way.